# Does @EntityListener works with @MappedSuperclass as well?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, entitylisteners

Folks!

If I define an Entity Class and annotate it with `@MappedSuperclass` and an `@EntityListener`,  does the listener also get called for lifecycle events within a child class?

Example:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(class=LastUpdateListener.class)
public abstract class Animal {
    @Id private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Calendar dateOfBirth;
    @Transient private int age;
    private Date lastUpdate;
    //getters and setters

    /**
     * Set my transient property at load time based on a calculation,
     * note that a native Hibernate formula mapping is better for this purpose.
     */
    @PostLoad
    public void calculateAge() {
        Calendar birth = new GregorianCalendar();
        birth.setTime(dateOfBirth);
        Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
        now.setTime( new Date() );
        int adjust = 0;
        if ( now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - birth.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < 0) {
            adjust = -1;
        }
        age = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - birth.get(Calendar.YEAR) + adjust;
    }
}

public class LastUpdateListener {
    /**
     * automatic property set before any database persistence
     */
    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void setLastUpdate(Cat o) {
        o.setLastUpdate( new Date() );
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, method annotated with @PostLoad in mapped superclass and LastUpdateListener's entity listener methods get called.

Such a thing as lifecycle event for mapped superclass itself does not even exist. As usual, it applies to subclass.

Comment: Have to say at this time this is not possible in eclipse toplink due this [bug][1]


  [1]: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=302194 "bug"