# @EntityListener never fired with wildlfy 10

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners (Rserve.class)
public class Example extends Analysis {
  private @Column @Basic int a;
  private @Column @Basic int b = 1;
  private @Column @Basic int c;
  //...
}
```

Listener like this:

```
public class Rserve extends Agent <R> { /* R is an annotation ... */ }

public abstract class Agent <E extends Annotation> {
  {
    System.out.println ("CREATING " + getClass ().getSimpleName ());
  }

  @PrePersist
  @PreUpdate
  @PreRemove
  @PostPersist
  @PostRemove
  @PostLoad
  @PostUpdate
  public void cb (Object a) {
    System.out.println ("CB(" + a + ")");
  }
}
```

The example entity gets persisted as a part of a bigger entity and is it persisted as I can see it in the database, but the listener is never called. I don't even see the listener created. I'm using Wildfly 10 via the maven plugin. I inject `EntityManager` via `@PersistenceContext`

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="mev" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:mev;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"></property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I am not sure if those the annotation related to the listeners can be in an abstract class

Comment: It should be according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936917/does-entitylistener-works-with-mappedsuperclass-as-well and other resources I've found

Comment: Apparently you're right though, bummer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a Wildfly issue with not calling back the superclasses of an entity listener. Callbacks work fine when put into the concrete class of the listener, and according Klaus Groenbaek, work fine in Spring Boot even on the superclass.